# jquery instant search based on keywords

Tags: jquery, search, livesearch

This plugin uses regular expression to sort content, in real-time, based on your search input.
Right now the script is searching just as you type.

here is the code:

```
$.fn.simpleContentSearch = function ( options ) {

var settings = {
    'active'    : 'active',
    'normal'    : 'normal',
    'searchList' : 'searchable tr',
    'searchItem' : 'td',
    'effect' : 'none' // fade, none
};

var base = this;
var options = $.extend(settings, options);

function startSearching(query)
{
    $( '.' + settings.searchList ).each(function () 
    {
        $(this).children( settings.searchItem ).each(function () 
        {
            var elem = $(this);

            if (!elem.html().match(new RegExp('.*?' + query + '.*?', 'i'))) {

                if( settings.effect == 'fade' ){
                    $(this).parent( '.' + settings.searchList ).fadeOut();
                } else {
                    $(this).parent( '.' + settings.searchList ).hide();
                }

            } else {

                if( settings.effect == 'fade' ){
                    $(this).parent( '.' + settings.searchList ).fadeIn();
                } else {
                    $(this).parent( '.' + settings.searchList ).show();
                }

                return false;
            }

            return;
        });
    });
}

return this.each(function() {    

    // On Blur
    base.blur(function () 
    {
        var elem = base;
        elem.removeClass().addClass(options.normal);
    });

    // On Focus
    base.focus(function () 
    {
        var elem = base;
        elem.removeClass().addClass(options.active);
    });

    //Keyup
    base.keyup(function () 
    {
        startSearching(base.val());
    });

    return this;

});
```

}

What I want to do is to create few buttons like : "text1"  "text2" and when you click on them to work to search for "text1" without having to type it. 
Any suggestions on how to do this ? 
 this is how the script works: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dynamyc/7Rm8U/7/light/)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i forked your fiddle and added the functionality you asked for.
http://jsfiddle.net/acturbo/PRNWe/2/

jquery

```
  $().ready(function() {
       console.clear();

        $('.searchFilter').simpleContentSearch({
            'active' : 'searchBoxActive',
            'normal' : 'searchBoxNormal',
            'searchList' : 'searchable tr',
            'searchItem' : 'td'
        });

       $(".search-btn").on("click", function(){
           $("#searchbox").val( $(this).data("search") );
           $('.searchFilter').keyup();
       });             
       $(".search-reset").on("click", function(){
           $("#searchbox").val( "");
           $('.searchFilter').keyup();
       });             

    });
```

html edit

```
<!-- Seach Box -->
        <input id="searchbox" type="text" class="searchFilter" onblur="if(this.value == '')this.value='Keyword(s)'" onfocus="this.value==this.defaultValue?this.value='':null" value="Keyword(s)" name="keyword">

            <a href="#" class="search-btn" data-search="text1 ">search 1</a>
            <a href="#" class="search-btn" data-search="intro ">search 2</a>
            <a href="#" class="search-reset">reset</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is working, I've changed the markup and now is not searching proper. I think I'm not adding the correct searchlist and searchitem elements. Could you please take a look over this http://jsfiddle.net/dynamyc/XARqy/6/. Is the same functionality just different markup.

Comment: in your new fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/XARqy/8/), line 91, 92, needs to be changed to this (it's working now): 

            'searchList' : 'dcwss-content ul li',
            'searchItem' : 'p'

Comment: to clarify what happened ... this is because you changed from <table> to <ul>, and what you were searching for now is contained in <p> tags, not in <td> tags. Everything was still working, but you had to update which elements you were searching in.

Comment: It's working but I don't understand why is not working on my website,the markup is generated by a shortcode, I've looked through console there are no errors. This is really frustrating I'm trying for several hours with to make this work but still no results.

Comment: can I post a link to my website to see what is happening ? or can you let an email to chat not for free of course

Comment: sure, post the link i'll take a look ... you can pay me with up-votes on my comments ;)

Comment: yes, that was the idea :D this is the [link](http://v2.letsplayibiza.com/?page_id=1532)

Comment: ok, i figured it out. it's working now: http://jsfiddle.net/6wY7d/3/ the change is this (lines 91,92):'searchList' : 'dcwss-content ul li', 'searchItem' : 'div'

Comment: I think I will post a new question because right now after I search I need to reorganize the lists because right now it just hide them and it doesn't look good with those empty spaces around it

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value of the search box to the value you for which want to automatically search, and then call its `keyup()` event to force it to search.

For example, you can create an input like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Intro" class="searchButton">
```

And then in `$(document).ready()` you can bind the following function to the click event:

```
$('.searchButton').click(function (eventObject) {
    $('.searchFilter').val(eventObject.target.value).keyup();
});
```

This will automatically search for the term you listed in the button's `value` attribute.

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gvH77/

Answer (score 0):

I found this on CodeCanyon and it is either exactly what you need, or its what you ended up actually making from the answers to this question:
http://codecanyon.net/item/simple-content-search/1850151?ref=arctic_ark